# Can't export signed ipa in flutter

Tags: macos, flutter

I made a flutter project in windows. Sent the whole project directory without build folder to Mac. On Mac I followed a flutter setup tutorial. Used command flutter pub get and proceeded to export with flutter build ios

On the Mac I'm signed into personal Apple ID, but I'm signing the app with other Apple ID which has the developer program active.

The problem is that export went smoothly until it asked for keychain. Tried personal keychain password and also Apple ID password from both personal and developer Apple. None of them worked. I canceled it and next time I try to export it won't even get to asking keychain.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You click allow or always allow?

Comment: I also experienced this clicking allow doesn't work but when i clicked always allow it worked for me